# Unique constraint using data in multiple tables (SQL / SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, unique-constraint

A top class called `Parametric` is used to create objects which can have parameters associated with them:

```
class Parametric(object):
 def __init__(self, name):
  self.name = name
  self.pars = []

class Foo(Parametric):
 def __init__(self, name, prop):
  self.prop = prop
  Parametric.__init__(self, name)

class Bar(Parametric):
 def __init__(self, name, prop):
  self.prop = prop
  Parametric.__init__(self, name)
```

I use SQLAlchemy for my ORM engine.

I want to impose a `UNIQUE` constraint that ensures that the combination (`name`,  `prop`) are unique  for a given class (e.g. only one instance of `Foo` can be called `"my_foo"` and have a `prop` value of, say `"my_prop"`), but I don't see how to reference the `name` column from `Parametric` in the `Foo` table `UNIQUECONSTRAINT` section.

Is this uniqueness something which can be imposed via `FOREIGN KEY` directives?

Comment: At the same time you have an instance of Foo called my_foo with a prop value of my_prop, can you also have an instance of Bar called my_foo (not a typo) with a prop called my_prop?

Comment: This is not sqlalchemy code. There are many different approaches to inheritance in sqlalchemy, but i can tell you right away that you can only setup in-base constraints (without creating additional tables) if you use shared table inheritance - your `prop` and `name` columns should be in the same table to do that.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to do what mixins do? http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/declarative.html#mixin-classes

Answer (score 5):

You could do this using [single table inheritance](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/declarative.html#single-table-inheritance).  However if your two columns are in different tables, you can't do *exactly* what you're trying to do (it is not possible to do a unique constraint across tables).

If single table inheritance is not an option, you probably want to either (1) enforce uniqueness in python, or (2) abandon sqlalchemy inheritance, and just use a foreign key to link Foo and Bar to Parametric.  You could foreign key to `name`, and THEN do a unique constraint on `name` and `prop`.

Answer (score 0):

in case 2 different tables you can do that in form validation check if it repeated.